# How do I get the id of a element in a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the id of an element within a form so I can tag the element as "false" or "true". Or, alternately, I need a way to associate a name with an element that can I pull in javascipt so I can change the associated value.

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.elements[i].value
```

Those lines of code is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit:

```
function initial(){
        if (localStorage.getItem("run") === null) {
                var form = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;

                for(var i = 0; i < 1 ; i++){
                    var id = form.elements[i].id;
                    sessionStorage.setItem(id,"false");
                }
            localStorage.setItem("run", true);
        }
    }
```

So basically when I run the page, I want a localStorage item attached to all the buttons on the screen. I want this to run once so I can set all the items to false. Problem is I don't know how to get the ids so I have a value to attach to the button. Any idea of how to accomplish a task like this.

Edit2:

```
function initial(){
        if (localStorage.getItem("run") === null) {
                var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
                var tot = document.getElementById("myForm").length;

                for(var i = 0; i < tot ; i++){
                    sessionStorage.setItem(form.elements[i].id,"false");
                }
            localStorage.setItem("run", true);
        }
    }
```

This is the new code. It mostly seems to work but for some reason only the first value is getting set to false. Or maybe it has to do with this function, I'm not sure.

```
 function loader(){
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        var tot = 5;

        for(var i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
            if(sessionStorage.getItem(form.elements[i].id) === "true"){
                document.getElementById(form.elements[i].id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
                return ;
            }else{
                document.getElementById(form.elements[i].id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyways, I'm running both of these at the same time when the page is executed so they are all set to false and turn red. But when a button is properly completed, the color of the button turns green.

Comment: You want to get the id so use `.id` instead of the `.value` : `form.elements[i].id`

Comment: Wait, why did this get downvoted? Anyways, I tried the id thing and it doesn't seem to work. So I will edit this to give more context.

Comment: Thank everyone for the help. There were two right answers so I gave it to the one that better helped me out. Anyways, there seems to be another issue, it only seems to be setting the first ID to false? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I don't actually know the question I should be asking so I'm not sure what to do with the XY problem. I appreciate the note - the purpose of using the localStorage was to have the initial function to only run once to set the "elements" to false until something on another page is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already storing all the elements in the form so it must be :

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
var id = form[i].id;
```

Or remove the `elements` part from the `form` variable like :

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
var id = form.elements[i].id;
```

Comment: I noticed the loop is set up to iterate once and will only ever access the first (zero indexed) element of the collection. Not sure if this is intentional or "dev" code and may cause issues elsewhere in the code if more elements are expected to be stored in `sessionStorage`.

Comment: This was intentional, I'm a bit confused on how it might cause issues. I'm not very good at JS so could you explain why? - also thank you all for the help!

Comment: In your code, you're already storing all the elements in the `form` variable when you do `var form = document.getElementById("myForm").elements` so this variable isn't representing the form but the list of elements so when you do `form.elements[i].id` you try to get the list of elements from the list of elements already stored in the `form` variable.

Comment: If you're only ever going to store the element at the `0` index you don't need a `for` loop. Having a loop suggests that you want to store more. Typically I would have expected the `for` loop to be written like this `for ( var i = 0, len = form.length; i < le; i++ )`. Since a loop was used, it's not unreasonable to think there would be code trying to access more than a single ID store with `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Oh, ok. I think I understand. I didn't read this correctly the first time. It seems to be similar to what zer00ne was talking about too. Thanks for the help. I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 2):

It's available via the `id` property on the element:

```
var id = form.elements[i].id;
```

More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) and [in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlelement).

Live Example:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
console.log("The id is: " + form.elements[0].id);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" id="theText">
</form>
```